# Are these two queries identical?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm seeing this query in my codes:

```
INSERT INTO comments (post_id, user_id, table_code, content, author_id, pinged_id, date_time)
SELECT ?,?,?,?,?,?,?
FROM qanda qa, users u
WHERE qa.id=? and author_id IS NULL
limit 1;
```

I've written query above already .. Now I believe `, user u` is redundant in my query. Am I right?

Do you know why I'm asking this question? Because always there is a reason in the behind of all my codes. Now I cannot remember what's the reason of writing this `, users u`. That's why I worry to remove it.

Anyway, removing `, users u` changes something? or it totally redundant?

Comment: Not really. If u is empty no row at all will be inserted. If u contains data, and also qa, then 1 row will be inserted.

Comment: No, adding the second table like that is doing a `CROSS JOIN` between the two tables (which is probably *not* what you're wanting)

Comment: To which table does the `author_id` belong?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `qanda`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `author_id` belongs to the `qanda` table, the implicit join to the `users` table serves no purpose.  In fact, it is a cross join, since there are no join conditions, which means it could be a real performance hog.  You can try using the following simplified `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO comments (post_id, user_id, table_code, content, author_id,
                      pinged_id, date_time)
SELECT ?,?,?,?,?,?,?
FROM qanda qa
WHERE qa.id=? AND author_id IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

But this doesn't explain what the `users` table is doing there in the first place.  Maybe you inherited this query from someone (or something) else, and at one time the join was being used for a legitimate reason.  Regardless, remove the debt now while you can easily do so.

Comment: Look, some people have written "no"  in the comments under my question, I mean, some people believe your query *(in your answer)* and mine *(in the question)* aren't identical. So are you sure they are identical?

Comment: AFAIK your original query is doing a cross join and so I would expect the records in the `qanda` table to get inserted multiple times, one time for each record in `qanda` which gets paired with a record in `users`.  Didn't you notice something strange about the data getting inserted?

Comment: Almost the same, at least as long as table u has data.

Comment: And for my information, Isn't that `LIMIT1` also redundant? Since `qa.id` is unique.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And yes, Sometimes the same comment will be inserted several times *(when I remove `LIMIT 1`)*

Comment: @MartinAJ Rats...I totally missed the `LIMIT 1` ... yes, the two were almost identical, but the join to `users` was totally not being used, and could possibly slow down the query.  Remove `users`, and if you want to `INSERT` all the records from `qanda` then remove the `LIMIT` statement.